Getting Error: Super expression must either be null or a function with react-slick
I'm using Next.js = 14.2.2 and React = ^18.
In my next.js app I have added 'react-slick' library to make a carousel which is implemented like this, It was working fine with repetition of each slide instead of map:
"use-client";

import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

export default function ImageSlider() {
  const texts = [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "Consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
    "Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua",
    "Ut enim ad minim veniam",
    "Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco",
  ];

  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    arrows: false,
  };

  return (
    <div className="image-slider-coverer">
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {texts.map((text, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-black/40 backdrop-blur-sm"></div>
            <p className="text-white">{text}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}

Now whenever instead of .map array method I hardcode each text repeating each style again and again then it works otherwise with the above code it shows following error Error: Super expression must either be null or a function
And in the console it is showing following errors
index.js:625 Uncaught Error: Super expression must either be null or a function
at _inherits (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/track.js:16:113)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/track.js:191:3)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/react-slick/lib/track.js:227:2)
I tried re-running the yarn and yarn dev, I reviewed the usage of "use-client"; at the top of the file, but it's keeps crashing :(
